# Are two halves of a convex polytope themselves convex?

Tags: geometry, polytopes, convex-geometry

Suppose I have an $n$-dimensional convex polytope $P$ which is the convex hull of some set of vertices $V$. Now suppose I take a hyperplane $T$ that intersects $P$ and slice $P$ into two parts: $P_1$, which is to one side of the hyperplane, and $P_2$, which is on the other. It seems intuitive to me that $P_1$ and $P_2$ should both be convex. Is this true in general? And is there a theorem that I could cite when making this assertion?

Comment: Yes. $P_i$'s are polytopes again. In fact a polytope is an intersection of finitely many half spaces.

Comment: @user251257 I am concerned specifically with their convexity in this case.

Comment: @Sally : "Geometry" is about as broad as it gets. $\qquad$

Comment: I meant convex polytopes. Sorry

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes, and it was edited in by the OP after my comment. The original version had one tag, [polytopes].

Comment: @Sally : Doesn't the word "polytopes" convey all information conveyed by the word "geometry" (and some more information beyond that)? $\qquad$

Answer (score 4):

The intersection of two convex sets (or infinitely many convex sets, for that matter) is convex.  That's not hard to prove by using the definition of convexity.

And half-spaces are convex.

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of half-spaces. It seems like that is exactly what I am describing.